# Spring data query with max limit and condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to get the item with the highest year and has a particular personal name. I'm trying this:

```
Foo findTopByOrderByYearDesc();
```

This work great, the problem is when I add a new param to filter results

```
Foo findTopByOrderByYearDescAndPersonName(@Param("person.name") final String name);
```

But I get this error:

> No property andPersonName found for type Foo!

I try this too but I get de same error:

```
Foo findTopByOrderByYearDescByPersonName(@Param("person.name") final String name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
Foo findTopByPersonNameOrderByYearDesc(@Param("person.name") final String name);
```

The first 'by' keyqord works as a delimiter [see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: This started being ludicrously expensive when run on a large table. I implemented it manually with a `select max(t.field) from Table t` JPQL query.